# Migration of SQL Server DB to HSQLDB alternative for varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, database, hsqldb, database-migration, type-conversion

I am working on requirement to migrate Microsoft SQL Server to HSQL Database.

What will be the alternative for *varchar(max)* from SQL Server to other data type in HSQL Database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VARCHAR with a large maximum size, for example VARCHAR(1000000). Check the maximum size of the strings in that column in the SQLServre database and use a larger value. If the strings are typically longer than 32000 characters, you can consider using CLOB instead.